# PowerApp - image not showing when stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, office365, powerapps

I'm doing a Hello World data app using Power Apps. It's simply displaying and editing a list I am connecting to an Azure SQL Server. I have a a table with column called UserImage, which is a Image data type. When I go into edit mode I can add an image and I can see something getting added to the binary column. I've tried converting the image to text (thinking a url or something textual might be going in) but it's funny encoded characters. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. The images don't display in list or view mode.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, the Gallery control in PowerApps doesn't provide any sort of special empty display message. You can easily add an empty message if you want one, though. Just add a Label control outside of the Gallery and bind the `Visible` property to `CountRows(Gallery1.AllItems) = 0` (with `Gallery1` replaced by whatever the name of your gallery is, of course). This will make it so the Label only shows when the Gallery is empty and you will be able to style the Label however you want.

Reference: I work on PowerApps. :)